# Permissions Not preperly set Ubuntu Samba 4

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I am in the middle of permissions chaos setting up my samba server and shares.  This is not a complicated setup but I cannot get the permissions to work:

Scenario:
Samba 4 on Ubuntu 19.04

5 users in the same group (company) need to access a Samba Share and have the ability to read, write, edit and delete files and folders in the share (regardless of the author).  The members of the group are the only individuals that have access to the share.  My SMB.CONF looks like this:

```
[global]
   workgroup = PREMPROVSOL
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.10.0/24
   bind interfaces only = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   unix charset = UTF-8
   dos charset = CP932
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 2777
   force create mode = 0777
   force directory mode = 2777


[Client-Billing]
    path= /server/Client-Billing/
    writeable = yes
    guest ok = no
    valid users = @company
    force group = company
```

I created a folder called 'Test' and when I examined the owner, it has the user who created the folder but all the permissions look correct:

`drwxrwsrwx+  2 theuser company 4.0K Jul 15 13:38  Test`

I have issued the following modifications to the Client-Billing folder:

```
sudo chmod g+s server/Client-Billing/
sudo chown root:company server/Client-Billing/
sudo chmod -R 0777 server/Client-Billing/
```

My problem is when a user creates a folder (from Win10 machines, another user cannot create, copy to, etc. a file in that folder.

Users can VIEW files created by other users but cannot edit an save them in the same folder.

When the user copies a file (say a PDF) into the folder the permissions on the file look odd and do not correspond with the SAMBA configuration:

`-rwxrwx---+ 1 theuser company 136K Jul 10 10:34 doc10284020190710104636.pdf`

I'm at a bit of a loss where to go from here.  What is it that I am missing?

***EDIT***

Been tinkering with the smb.conf file and found that

```
[Client-Billing]
    path= /server/Client-Billing/
    writeable = yes
    guest ok = no
    valid users = @company
    force group = company
    create mode = 0775
    directory mode = 2775
```

and

```
[Corporate]
    path= /server/Corporate/
    writeable = yes
    guest ok = no
    valid users = @corporate
    force group = corporate
    create mode = 0775
    directory mode = 2775
```

Have the exact same configurations; however, `Corporate` share works perfectly and the `Client-Billing` share has permission issues. Still befuddled.  Any insight?